# how make a slide show in reacjs?

Tags: reactjs, slideshow

I am trying to make a slide show by reactjs. In the slide show the next button work perfectly but the previous button have problem.
You can show demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/124358/).
please help me to resolve this problem.

thanks.

next button handler that remove next value from next array and add current number to pre array.and i have one case that length of next array become 0 in this case push the number after next to this array and remove from pre array. this algorithm works perfect and i use this concepts in pre button handler but in there pre length become 0 this approach does not work.

next button handler:

```
onNextHandler = () => {
    let currentIndex = this.state.current;
    let nextIndex = this.checkIndex( currentIndex + 1 );
    let pre = [ ...this.state.pre ];
    let next = [ ...this.state.next ];
    const nextIndexInNext = next.indexOf( this.numbers[ nextIndex ] );
    next.splice( nextIndexInNext, 1 );
    pre.push( this.numbers[ currentIndex ] );
    if ( next.length === 0 ) {
      next.push( this.numbers[ this.checkIndex( nextIndex + 1 ) ] );
      const indexNextInPre = pre.indexOf( this.numbers[ this.checkIndex( nextIndex + 1 ) ] )
      pre.splice( indexNextInPre, 1 );
    }
    this.setState( {
      current: nextIndex,
      pre,
      next,
    } );
  }
```

pre next button handler:

```
  onPrevHandler = () => {
    let currentIndex = this.state.current;
    let prevIndex = this.checkIndex( currentIndex - 1 );
    let pre = [ ...this.state.pre ];
    let next = [ ...this.state.next ];
    const prevIndexInPre = pre.indexOf( this.numbers[ prevIndex ] );
    pre.splice( prevIndexInPre, 1 );
    next.splice( 0, 0, this.numbers[ currentIndex ] );
    if ( pre.length === 0 ) {
      pre.push( this.numbers[ this.checkIndex( prevIndex - 1 ) ] );
      const indexNextInPre = next.indexOf( this.numbers[ this.checkIndex( prevIndex - 1 ) ] );
      next.splice( indexNextInPre, 1 );
    };
    this.setState( {
      current: prevIndex,
      pre,
      next,
    } );
  };
```

on render function i map each array to li element and finally concat them to one array like below.

```
const pre = this.state.pre;
    const pres = pre !== null
      ? pre.map( num => {
        return <li key={ num } value={ num} className="before">{ num }</li>
      } )
      : null;
    const next = this.state.next;
    const nexts = next !== null
      ? next.map( num => {
        return <li key={ num } value={ num } className="after">{ num }</li>
      } )
      : null;
    const current = [ <li key={ this.state.current+1 } value={ this.state.current + 1 } className="current">{ this.numbers[ this.state.current ] }</li> ];

    let numsList = pres.concat( current, nexts );
```

when i change the concat like below:

```
let numsList = nexts.concat( current, pres );
```

in this case the pres button works perfectly but does not next button handler.

Comment: Does it need to be in react? Can't you use a presentation framework like reveal?

Comment: i am new in react and it is only for practise.

Comment: can you describe the "problem" more detailed please - for me it seems to work?

Comment: when press button '<' that count down slides, the slide when become 1 and then must become 5 the occurs problem.

Comment: Can you clarify it more? It seems working looking at your fiddle.